# Java Canvas - Rectangle2D Scales when Moving

Tags: java, java-canvas

I am drawing a series of rectangles on a Canvas. The rectangles are supposed to move on an angle. For some reason, when they move, they scale up:

```
xPos += xSpeed;
yPos += ySpeed;
updateBounds(xPos, yPos, width, height);
```

My UpdateBounds method:

```
public void updateBounds(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
    bounds.setRect(x, y, w, h);
}
```

Bounds is a Rectangle2D object.
And my Drawing method:

```
g.fillRect((int) bounds.getX(), (int) bounds.getY(),
                (int) bounds.getMaxX(), (int) bounds.getMaxY());
```

Why am I getting this behaviour?

Comment: What is a `bounds` variable class?

Comment: Is there any change of `width` or `height` variables in code which is not included in your question?

Comment: No. Everything that happens to the bounds. Is shown in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Graphics.fillRect()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect-int-int-int-int-) accepts a width and height parameter, not the largest x and y position of the rectangle to draw.

The third and fourth parameters to `fillRect` should be Rectangle2D's [getWidth()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html#getWidth%28%29) and [getHeight()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html#getHeight--).

As a reference, a [link to what getMaxX() would give you](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html#getMaxX%28%29).

Comment: Nice answer, not mentioned it +1